# Preserve HTML formatting <datalist>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building `<datalist>` options as below:

```
data.suggestions.forEach(function(element) {
    $('datalist').append(`<option value="${element['description'].split(' ')[0].replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')}">${element['description']}</option>`);
});
```

My `element['description']` has HTML tags, which I would like to preserve. However, the appended children have their HTML formatting stripped.

Please advise.

Comment: Please Clarify your requirements and code

Comment: `<option>` tag only accepts text. Use a dropdown type script instead if you need formatting. Or add a data attribute to reference back to the original array if that's what you need

Comment: Do you know any components that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Split function returns an array of element.
If you want only the first word, then try this

```
var str = element['description'].substring(0, element['description'].indexOf(' '))).replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```

then

```
$('datalist').append('<option value="+str+" >element['description']</option>');
```

Comment: This is not how you use variables with backquotes, but if your syntax would have been correct, how is this relevant?

Comment: you think that you did. :)

Comment: I'm trying to help you here not argue.